# Activity will not instantiate

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have added in the functionality for the ArrayAdapter however the activity will not now instantiate. Everything worked perfectly before I added the ArrayAdapter for the listview and the ChatActivity is in the manifest. I have been trying to work this out for a while and im sure its something simple, I just cant see it.

Here is the code.

```
import com.DrawTastic.Networking.LocalBinder;

public class ChatActivity extends ListActivity implements Runnable, OnClickListener {

private MyView myView;
private Networking mService;
private boolean mBound = false;
PrintWriter writer;
BufferedReader reader;
ObjectInputStream send;
ObjectOutputStream messSend;
ObjectInputStream messRec;
private EditText Text;

private ArrayAdapter<Message> mAdapter;
private ArrayList<Message> mMesseges = new ArrayList<Message>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat);

    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, mMesseges);

    myView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.MyView1);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

    Text.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Thread bob = new Thread(this);
    //bob.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Networking.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Called when a button is clicked (the button in the layout file attaches
 * to this method with the android:onClick attribute)
 */

/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get
        // LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
        myView.setService(mService);
        getDrawOIS();
        getMessOOS();
        getMessOIS();

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
        mService = null;
        myView.setService(null);
    }
};

public void getDrawOIS() {
    send = mService.getImageOis();
}

public void getMessOIS() {
    messRec = mService.getMessageOis();
}

public void getMessOOS() {
    messSend = mService.getMessageOops();
}

public ChatActivity(ObjectInputStream stream) {
    this.messRec = stream;
}

public void oopsMess(Message mess) {
    try {
        messSend.writeObject((Message) mess);
        messSend.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            while (true) {
                Message mess = (com.DrawTastic.Message) messRec.readObject();
                mAdapter.add(mess);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Message mess = new Message(Text.toString(), "Username");
    oopsMess(mess);
    Text.setText(null);
}
```

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">


<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.99">

    <view class="com.DrawTastic.MyView"
         android:id="@+id/MyView1" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"       
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"/>



</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="150px">


    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Send"
         android:onClick="onClick" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/input"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>


    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/input" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_height="100dp"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Stack Trace :

```
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.DrawTastic/com.DrawTastic.ChatActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.DrawTastic.ChatActivity
    03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.DrawTastic.ChatActivity
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
03-27 17:12:22.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(364):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no additional "Caused by" stanza below the one you have listed here? Also, since your code listing ends before the class does, are you sure that you do not have a constructor on `ChatActivity`?

Comment: No that is the entire class and the resulting stack

Comment: That's very strange. `InstantiationException` comes from stuff like having a constructor, or the class not being public, or stuff like that. Unless `ChatActivity` is an inner class of something, I don't see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *do* have a constructor:

```
public ChatActivity(ObjectInputStream stream) {
    this.messRec = stream;
}
```

Delete this. First, it will never be called. Second, it is preventing your activity from being instantiated. Android will use the zero-argument constructor, and you do not have one defined.